# Should I use a list or a dictionary?

Tags: python, list

I've read the question already about using a list, dictionary or a tuple but it doesn't answer my specified question

if I wanted an array say with the values of

```
array(1,2,3,4, "name" => "someone", "age" => array())
```

should I use a list or a dictionary? also, is it possible to have a multidimensional list or dictionary?

Order does matter here, also, I want to be able to access them using the key, for example

```
array["name"] would return "someone"
```

Comment: We need some more information here: Does order matters? How would you like to access the "name" and "age" elements of your array. By index or key?

Comment: @BleedingFingers How do you have a list with the values I specified in the array above in Python?

Comment: use list = `[1, 2, 3, 4, {"name" : "someone", "age" : []}]`

Comment: I think an `OrderedDict` with dummy keys for the integers should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your use-case only a dictionary would help, because what you are expecting is to pass a key not an index to `array`. And only a `dict` takes key against which it returns a value. Unlike list which take in an index.